# CollectionView in tableViewCell MVVM

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, rx-swift

I am building an app in Swift 4 using MVVM non reactive. I would like to call viewmodel updates from the tableView's View model in order not to turn it into spagetthi code. Instead of creating one view model for each collectionViewCell I am trying to update from main ViewModel.

```
//Spaghetti option (VM - ViewModel , VC - ViewController) 
//TableVC - TableVM 
//Cell- CellVM 
//CollectionCell- CollectionVM
```

And models and managers updating. I am using the method below to delegate back to the Main TableViewController to give the MainViewModel all responsibility. Since I have multiple CollectionViews in different cells I think this is the best way to do. Any suggestions?

```
func setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate<D: UICollectionViewDataSource & UICollectionViewDelegate>(dataSourceDelegate: D, forRow row:Int){
    self.collectionView.delegate = dataSourceDelegate
    self.collectionView.dataSource = dataSourceDelegate
    self.collectionView.tag = row
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: This question is probably better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You're really much better off creating a viewmodel for each cell. The spaghetti part comes when you do the binding.